# Use toFixed() to remove extra digits for all elements of a matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that for an array it can be done like this:

```
anArray = anArray.sum.map(function(elem){
    return Number(elem.toFixed(2));
});
```

But how can it be done for a bi-dimensional array?

This is my approach:

```
aMatrix = aMatrix.reduce( function (r, a) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i, j) {
        r[i][j] = r[i][j].toFixed(2);
    });
    return r;
}, []);
```

I tried only to remove the extra digits first, it must be added `Number()` also to remove the trailing zeros.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share a sample input and output in your question.

Comment: `matrix = matrix.map(row => row.map(col => Number(col.toFixed(2))));`?

Comment: You could use recursion: https://jsfiddle.net/xvmzfep0/2/

Comment: @user3654571 please see my (extensive) note below about why you shouldn't actually do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nesting [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls to get the result:

```js
var matrix = [[1.234, 4.123123, 3.1235134512], [23.12312, 90.123123, 3.123123]];

var result = matrix.map(function(subArray){
  return subArray.map(function(elem) {
    return Number(elem.toFixed(2));
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do *NOT* use the results of `.toFixed` as actual numbers.  Its sole purpose is to round numbers for *presentation purposes*, hence why it returns a string.

Use e.g. `Math.round(n * 100.0) / 100.0` if you really must use numbers of that precision when calculating, but bear in mind that in computers' binary floating point representations of numbers it is often not possible to express those numbers exactly.

To demonstrate this, see what happens if you try to evaluate:

```
> (0.03).toFixed(19)
"0.0299999999999999989"
```

It is almost always better to use numbers without rounding them, and then only round them at display time.

If your numbers are actually representing a currency and the precise results matter (e.g. for tax calculation purposes) then you shouldn't be using floating point at all.   Use integer math instead, and count in e.g. cents instead of dollars.

From the comments it appears that you actually want to display numbers with *up to* two decimal places, i.e. like `.toFixed(2)` but with trailing zeroes removed, and the manipulation of the nested 2D array is required only because you hadn't found a way to do that with an Angular directive.

To do that, IMHO it's better to remain in "string" space rather than abusing the `Number` constructor.  You could use for example:

```
myvalue.toFixed(2).replace(/0+$/, '')
```

Comment: NB: community wiki, since I know this isn't an "answer" to the question asked, but what I needed to say is too long for a comment.

Comment: So, is there a way to remove the unwanted digits in a safer way than with `toFixed()` or not and the best solution is to round them only on presentation? In my particular case I don't find a better solution. I'm working with AngularJS and I must put on a screen a table containing data on the rows and columns and on the last column the sum of the values of each row. I use interpolation to print the values, in html in use this : `{{$ctrl.myvalue}}` . I tried to use `toFixed(2)` there and it works but doesn't remove the zeros, I cannot use `Number()` inside interpolation.

Comment: Ah, it's an XY Problem :)   Your real problem is that you want the output of `.toFixed()` except that you also want trailing zeroes removed.    I think Angular would let you do `{{ $ctrl.myvalue.toFixed(2).replace(/0*$/, '') }}`

Answer (score 0):

The same way you loop throw the one dimensional array, you can loop throw each array inside of parent array:

```
var newArr = anArray.sum.map(function(elem){
    return elem.map( function( subElem ){
      return subElem.toFixed(2); 
    });
});
```

Or, in `es6` syntax:

```
anArray.sum.map( sub => sub.map( subSub => subSub.toFixed(2)));
```

And then you don't need to return anything, just update the value inside the `map` function.

Comment: "And you don't need to return anything, just update the value inside the map function." in map i think you need to return. i got `[undefined, undefined]` with this code. ... when adding the returns its the same code as @Ori

Comment: @RolandStarke my bad, I rushed to update and did not put the desired code. edited. thank you!

Comment: @Alnitak I took care of it before I saw your comment, thank you anyway!